# I want to create a camera and list data gallery in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, camera, image-gallery

I want to make a gallery where there is a camera in the first part like this picture

[image: //i.stack.imgur.com/VdyNu.png]

I have tried react-native-customized-image-picker but it doesn't support typescript, apart from that I have tried react-native-image-crop-picker and react-native-image-picker but it doesn't work as I expected, is it do you have to customize it yourself?